# How to make wall push the player in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to make wall push the player ?

i had tried to use transform.translate, however i found out directly manipulating transform
component of an object ignores physic, and someone suggest me to use force instead.

however, when i use force, the wall 
just stop when it hit my player, as if my player can't be moved.
Below are my code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class left : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        rigidbody.AddForce (-40 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

        if (transform.position.x < -14) {
            transform.position = new Vector3(15,15,908);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody can help you make your code work if you don't post any of the relevant code. Look at other questions people have posted here and try to improve yours to be more answerable.

Comment: Have you attached a rigidbody to the player?

Comment: i already had, but the result is still same, the wall either stop, or start spinning due to trying to move but blocked by the player

Answer (score 0):

Increase the mass of the wall or reduce the mass if the player

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should put a collider on both the box and the player. Then create a script on the player. Something that would tell it that when the box collided with the player, it would move to the destined position, depending on the force applied.

something like

```
OncollideO(){
player.transform.position.x -= Time.deltaTime * 1;
}
```

you do not have to set the vectors manually to be able to move them.

you may also use left, right, up, and down in moving gameobjects.
might as well as tell you to research about LERP which may be  able to help you in coding it.